# How to do a solar charging circuit and a discharging circuit to a single battery?

Tags: solar-cell, charger, lipo

I have a solar charge circuit with 6v solar input and a 5 V, 1 A USB output and connected to a 3.7V LiPo battery. Since I needed

1. battery % display
2. 5 V, 2 A USB output
   I needed to add a circuit for discharge only.

How do I connect these two circuits and he battery together?

Summary

1. Charging circuit - 6 V input 3.7 V battery output
2. Discharging circuit - 3.7 V battery, 2 A output
3. Battery - 3.7 V 7000 mAh LiPo Battery

Comment: How much current can your 6V solar panel put out?

Comment: For battery status indicator you can use a LM339 IC. It's a 4 Led voltmeter. For 2A/5V check first if your battery can be drained with 3A more. Otherwise it cannot be done.

Comment: thank you Michal. yes I have checked the battery is fine. The doubt I'm having is 'Can I simply connect the battery terminals of these two circuits to the battery in parallel

Comment: Check where is the battery protecting circuit. You must connect these two circuits after it, not before.